# How to take specific data from XML file and insert into specific div classes?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, html

What I'm trying to do is create a webpage with a gridlike structure, where some boxes are big and others small, without having to code everything in html. I created the div structure as you can see here:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
<div class="inline">
    <div class="big-tile">
        <img class="big-tile-image" />
        <div class="big-tile-description">
            <div class="name"></div>
            <div class="rating"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I'd like to fill in the appropriate div blocks from an XML file using Javascript. This is the javascript I have now:

```
            function loadXMLDoc() {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "imgdb.xml", true);
                xmlhttp.send();

                var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                    var large = 340;
                    var tileName = new Array();
                    var tileRating = new Array();
                    var tilePhoto = new Array();
                    var tileSize = new Array();

                    for (i=0;i<=18;i++) {
                        tileSize[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("girl")[i].childNodes[3];
                        tileName[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("girl")[i].childNodes[0];
                        tileRating[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("girl")[i].childNodes[2];
                        tilePhoto[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("girl")[i].childNodes[1];

                        if (tileSize[i] == "large") {
                            document.getElementsByClassName("big-tile-image").setAttribute("src", tilePhoto[i]);                    
                        }
                    }
            }
```

I didn't try to fill out the other blocks like rating and name. I wanted to see if the code worked by displaying the first image. Obviously it doesn't so my question is what am I doing wrong?

{I'm trying to create something similar to the chrome web store as viewed in chrome}

Thanks for any help you guys can give!

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the values from XML in the controller and get the values in the appropriate div.Try this

```
foreach (XmlNode node in Document.SelectNodes("girl"))
            {
                s.size = node["Size"].InnerText;
                s.name = node["Name"].InnerText;
                s.rating = node['Rating"].InnerText;
            }
```